# Is it possible to nest multiple overset? otherwise how?

Tags: r, overset

I have a `ggplot2` plot for which I'd like to align text to some plot related boundaries e.g. between axis ticks. The process that creates the annotation text is automatic and needs to account for word-wrap and alignment. I could do that book-keeping y and x coordinates but is not fun and is somewhat reinventing the wheel.

The good news is this r plot framework `ggplot2` can be made to understand TeX and parse it using `latex2exp`. So my question is whether using Tex I can word-wrap align text multi-lines using `\overset`? is there any other solution. As I understand overset has only two lines `\overset{first line}{second line}` but I need something more general e.g. nesting \overset?

For example I have text like this (wit the x axis boundaries):

```
     | This is a sample |
     |  very very long  |
     |    annotation    |
```

Note that it is word-wrapped and center aligned.

Comment: You could try `\parbox{<width>}{\centering this is a sample very very long annotation}`.

Comment: and `\overset` is nestable, but without further tweaking results in different fontsizes for `\overset{\overset{a}{b}}{c}`.

Comment: why not overset an `\mbox` or a `\parbox`?

Comment: Why are you using TeX at all, and not `\n`, e.g. `text(x,y,"this\nis\na very\nlong text")`?